# moving from Enthought to Anaconda

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, anaconda

I couldn't install Enthought on my work computer so I put Anaconda on instead.  I also have Python 3 on my computer.  I have a few questions:

1)  When I type

```
where python
```

in my command prompt, I get the following path:

c:\Users\mayerk\AppData\Local\enthought\Canopy\User\Scripts\python.exe

Should this be changed?  If so, how?

2)  How do I install conda?  Even though I have Anaconda 3 installed, I don't see it.

Again, on the command prompt, when I type

```
conda --version
```

It says "'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

3)  Do I need the 'virtualenv' program if I have 'pip'?  If so, how do I install that?

Comment: did you install conda to path? `conda` comes with the Anaconda install. You should have it. Worst thing that happens is uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2) When you install anaconda on windows now, it doesn't automatically add Python or Conda to your path.

If you don’t know where your conda and/or python is, you type the following commands into your anaconda prompt (this comes with the install of anaconda)

[image]

Next, you can add **Python and Conda** to your path by using the setx command in your command prompt.
[image]

Next close that command prompt and open a new one. Congrats you can now use conda and python

3) Since you are looking to use conda, you can use [conda environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). You can also use virtualenv, but if you are using conda, might as well take advantage of conda environments.

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate it.